# Javascript on Multiple DIVs

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I am using a Wordpress Theme (Incipiens) that has a show/hide Javascript to show a map on the contact page http://demo.themedev.me/wordpress_themes/incipiens/contact-us/

I want to use this function on a page multiple times to show/hide galleries.

```
<div class="map">
<div class="map_top">                        
<hr class="toolbox toolbox1">
</div>
<hr class="vertical_sep0">
<a class="show_map" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
<div class="map_container"><div class="thismap"><iframe>........</iframe></div>
</div>
```

I have this working but the call to the js opens all divs. I therefore put a unique div id round each gallery and slightly changed the javscript...

```
<div class="map">
<div class="map_top">                        
<hr class="toolbox toolbox1">                        
</div>
<hr class="vertical_sep0">
<a href="javascript:unhide('silestone')" class="show_map"></a>
<div id="silestone">
<div class="map_container">
[show_gallery width="124" height="124" galleryid="527"][/show_gallery]
</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

It works but very oddly, sometimes the right one opens, sometimes the wrong one...not sure what i'm doing wrong, should I just have one javascript call that contains the ID's to all divs? If so how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shown the actual script you use for toggling, I assume you mean something like this (taken from the page) -

```
function (){
    $(this).toggleClass('hide_map');
    $('.map_container').slideToggle(400);
}
```

I would change that to -

```
function unhide(id){
    $(this).toggleClass('hide_map');
    $('#' + id).find('.map_container').slideToggle(400);
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but where did you find that JS function?

Comment: (Using Chrome) I went to the link you mentioned, right clicked on the + button and selected "Inspect Element". There, within the Console panel, I entered - `$._data($0, "events")`. Expanding the object gave me the function. More specifically, `$._data($0, "events").click[0].handler` (I have a Developer Tools extension that simplifies this process).

Comment: I use Chrome and the inspect element function all the time, when I do the same it just highlights the line <a class="show_map" href="javascript:void(0)"></a> am I looking in the right place, can't see under elements or console?

Comment: ooh sorry only saw part of message orignially I will have another look

Comment: Sorry, don't seem to be able to locate it, not sure even where I can enter that script onto the console, just have a load of unsafe javascript warnings. Don't suppose you could see what file that JS was coming from?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I am new in StackOverflow, so I keep pressing Enter in comments before I finish typing the whole thing. :(

Comment: Below the warnings, you can type. Just press Escape twice and start typing.

Comment: Oh, I bet the code looks for elements with the "show_map" class and adds a click event listener to them and calls the said function. You will have to locate that code (or change the class to something else and add a selector for it within the CSS rule that provides the +/X style) and detach it from your elements, or else it would probably toggle additional elements.

Comment: Thanks, working on something else currently but will report back if I fix it, thanks for the help though mate

Comment: And, yes, it can be found within http://demo.themedev.me/wordpress_themes/incipiens/wp-content/themes/incipiens/js/scripts.js?ver=3.4.1 I found it using Control + Shift + F (do it while you are in the Developer Tools) and looked for "show_map" (without the quotes). The last result is the said function.